# pip install from repo programmatically results in error "No such file or directory"

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip

On win 10, I'm installing to py 3.6 venv. From terminal

```
pip install --upgrade git+git://github.com/larochew/py_daemoniker.git@cfd8a669975c217f6df7063be8cb8fbc08b5f0df#egg=daemoniker
```

Works fine:

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 192.5728.105)
  Running command git clone -q git://github.com/larochew/py_daemoniker.git 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g9do107m\daemoniker'
Collecting daemoniker
  Cloning git://github.com/larochew/py_daemoniker.git (to revision cfd8a669975c217f6df7063be8cb8fbc08b5f0df) to c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-g9do107m\daemoniker
  Running command git checkout -q cfd8a669975c217f6df7063be8cb8fbc08b5f0df
Installing collected packages: daemoniker
    Running setup.py install for daemoniker: started
    Running setup.py install for daemoniker: finished with status 'done'
Successfully installed daemoniker-0.2.3
```

But from code:

```
try:
    from pip import main as pipmain
except:
    from pip._internal import main as pipmain

pipmain.main(['install', '--upgrade', 'git+git://github.com/larochew/py_daemoniker.git@cfd8a669975c217f6df7063be8cb8fbc08b5f0df#egg=daemoniker'])
```

Results in:

```
Collecting daemoniker
  Cloning git://github.com/larochew/py_daemoniker.git (to revision cfd8a669975c217f6df7063be8cb8fbc08b5f0df) to c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-64iunozy\daemoniker
  Running command git clone -q git://github.com/larochew/py_daemoniker.git 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-64iunozy\daemoniker'
  Running command git checkout -q cfd8a669975c217f6df7063be8cb8fbc08b5f0df
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-tracker-qu0hrtol\\9eeeef850bab53900fe60a86b33217ba700f6f3907aadc10a37ed11f'
```

Although normal packages are installed without errors.

Comment: It most likely won't solve your actual issue, but I would advise against using _pip_ as a library. Better follow this advice instead: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I needed to install requirements silently from code under windows, code below did the trick:

```
        subprocess.check_call(
            [executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--upgrade', '-r', config['requirements_file']],
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE
        )
```

Without `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` stdout from pip will go to current process. Also this will not create terminal in win. Thnx to lead from @sinoroc comment